# adding a startup script on a server

Tags: linux, shell

I am logged into my server as root and tried to run this command:

```
# update-rc.d -f tk10xbooting.sh default 5
```

Here tk10xbooting.sh is a script I want to run at every sever restart. But when I run it, the result is output like this :

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
usage: update-rc.d [-n] [-f] <basename> remove
       update-rc.d [-n] <basename> defaults [NN | SS KK]
       update-rc.d [-n] <basename> start|stop NN runlvl [runlvl] [...] .
       update-rc.d [-n] <basename> disable|enable [S|2|3|4|5]
        -n: not really
        -f: force

The disable|enable API is not stable and might change in the future.
```

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: ooh got it. only one letter was missing it is 'defaults' not 'default'

Comment: you can add that as an answer and accept it yourself :)

Comment: @SiGanteng ya will do that LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of `updte-rc.d` (according to the output you gave) is different than you provide:

- you use default which should have been default**s**
- `-f` is only used for the `remove` command
- you might need to use `05` instead of `5` as the syntax tells that it should be `NN` (but it might work as 5, I do not know)